# проверка полей Рефлексия Java

Tags: java

Задам мб глупый вопрос, но все же как проверить поля с помощью рефлексии и если поля написаны не правильно либо пустые выбрасывало исключения

Comment: Зачем? Что вынуждает вас выполнять в рантайме ту роботу, которую должен был сделать компилятор?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае подойдет метод [getField()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-):

```
try {
    MyClassName.class.getField("myFieldName");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Также рекомендую ознакомиться с прочими методами класса [Class<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: MyClassName.class.getField("myFieldName"); это проверка поля на правильность ввода?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно лучше воспользоваться методом getFields(), который возвратит массив Fields[] всех полей класса, а дальше проверяйте их как вам необходимо.